# AlertDialog appears only late (weird behaviour) Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am uploading data to a webserver. On my fragment I have a button to start the upload. There are two phases what I am trying to have the user notification done via a none-cancellable AlertDialog solution.

When I am pressing the upload button, preparation for the upload is starting I am setting up the AlertDialog and presenting it. Once the physical upload is starting, I am using the same AlertDialog, but changing the message in it to show the progress of the upload.

***** Now the issue is the following ******
When I setup the AlertDialog and call the Show method, it does not display the AlertDialog. But once the upload is started and the progress is updated I just call the setMessage method and at this point the AlertDialog appears.

The relevant codes are the followings:

The submitbutton.setOnClickLictener is in the onViewCreated()

```
  submitbutton.setOnClickListener {
        requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
            SubmitAd()
        }
    }
```

I have tried here the run the SubmitAd() on the UIThread, if it helps, but it is the same without it.

SubmitAd is showing the Dialog. (Actually at this point nothing is shown.

```
fun SubmitAd() {
    var addInApp: Boolean = false
    ToBePurchased = 0

    if (CheckCanUpload()) {
        var AlertView = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
        AlertView.setTitle("Hirdetés feltöltés")
        AlertView.setMessage("A feltöltés előkészítése hosszabb ideig is eltarhat, kérjük várjon!")
        AlertView.setCancelable(false)

        DialogToShow = AlertView.create()
        DialogToShow!!.show()

        purchaseLoop = 0

        UploadWithPurchase()
    } else {
        var AlertView = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
        AlertView.setTitle("Hirdetés hiba")
        AlertView.setMessage("A hirdetése hiányos. Kérjük töltse ki az összes mezőt és csatoljon fotót a hirdetéséhez!")
        AlertView.setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, which ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        DialogToShow = AlertView.create()
        DialogToShow!!.show()
    }
}
```

In UploadWithPurchase() the Playstore purchase handling is done, but if there is no purchase at all, it is just going through a loop, which calls UploadWithPurchase() recursively until all possible purchases are checked, then it goes to the real Upload() which calls an Http request to upload the data and reports back via an interface the progress of the upload process.

The Webhelper returns the progress like this:

```
override fun WebHelperProgress(id: String, progress: Float) {
    if (DialogToShow != null) {
        DialogToShow!!.setMessage("Feltöltés folyamatban. Kérem várjon! ... ${progress.toInt()}%")
    }
}
```

When this method is called, the AlertDialog appears.

Whatever I have tried, does not help. AlertDialog does not show up at the first call, but no clue why.

EDIT later: I have figured out that the AlertDialog is actually appears once it comes out from the recursive loop, but I do not know how to force it to be displayed before it starts the loop. That would be my aim to notify the user that a longer process is starting. It meaningless to start the process and the user does not know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve it by putting the purchaseLoop to a separate Thread like this.

```
fun SubmitAd() {
var addInApp: Boolean = false
ToBePurchased = 0

if (CheckCanUpload()) {
    var AlertView = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
    AlertView.setTitle("Hirdetés feltöltés")
    AlertView.setMessage("A feltöltés előkészítése hosszabb ideig is eltarhat, kérjük várjon!")
    AlertView.setCancelable(false)

    DialogToShow = AlertView.create()
    DialogToShow!!.show()

    purchaseLoop = 0

    ******** SOLUTION HERE ********

    Thread {
        UploadWithPurchase()
    }.start()

    *******************************

} else {
    var AlertView = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
    AlertView.setTitle("Hirdetés hiba")
    AlertView.setMessage("A hirdetése hiányos. Kérjük töltse ki az összes mezőt és csatoljon fotót a hirdetéséhez!")
    AlertView.setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, which ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
    DialogToShow = AlertView.create()
    DialogToShow!!.show()
}
```

}